# hql fetch on right outer join

Tags: hibernate, hql

[Scenario]

I have two tables - Region and Substation.
A Region can have many substations but a substation can only belong to one region.
Also a region cannot have any substation. i.e. a region without a substation.

In the model class, I have two classes, Region and Substation.
Substation contains one field of Region type, and this is how I have established foreign key relation between a Region and a Substation.

I am doing right outer join on Hibernate Query Language  like this:

```
from Substation sub right outer join fetch sub.region
```

The reason why I am doing right outer join is because in the list that is returned after query execution, I also want to show regions which does not have a substation.

[Database]

This is how my region table looks:

```
mysql> select * from region;
+----+----------------+-------+
| id | name           | state |
+----+----------------+-------+
|  1 | Entire Network |       |
|  4 | aa             | AK    |
-------Data abbreviated due to space consumption-------
```

This is how my substation table looks:

```
mysql> select * from substation;
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----+
| name    | lon         | lat       | region_id | id |
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----+
| aga     |    3.000000 | 23.000000 |         1 |  1 |
| sjstest |   46.000000 | 22.100000 |         7 |  2 |
----------Data abbreviated due to space consumption--------
```

After right outer join, this is what I get:

```
mysql> select * from substation right outer join region on region.id=substation.region_id;
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+----+----------------+-------+
| name    | lon         | lat       | region_id | id   | id | name           | state |
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+----+----------------+-------+
| aga     |    3.000000 | 23.000000 |         1 |    1 |  1 | Entire Network |       |
| addtest | -104.501953 | 47.813155 |         1 |    8 |  1 | Entire Network |       |
| NULL    |        NULL |      NULL |      NULL | NULL |  4 | aa             | AK    |
----------Data abbreviated due to space consumption-----------------------------------
```

As you can see, in the last row, the first part is null because this region "aa" does not have any substation.

[Problem]

If there are regions that have no substation, I expect hibernate to return me a Substation object with all other data set to null and only region data set.

But what I get is that hibernate returns me null objects whenever it finds data like the 3rd row.

So my question is that, why hibernate is not doing eager loading when I am specifying fetch in the query. After doing eager loading, it should initialize a new Substation object and set region in it.

In any case, it should never return me a null.

[Example]

Just for demonstation, this is what I get when I print the results

```
com.tollgrade.smartgrid.model.Substation@10cc6578
com.tollgrade.smartgrid.model.Substation@ed192112
null
```

Observe that the third one is null because it had data like the 3rd row I mentioned in my database output. It should not be null. It must contain a substaion object that has all other fields null except for the region field.

[DEBUG]

This is the HQL debug output:

```
014-05-15 15:50:31.122 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - select substation0_.id as id91_0_, region1_.id as id85_1_, substation0_.region_id as region2_91_0_, substation0_.name as name91_0_, substation0_.lon as lon91_0_, substation0_.lat as lat91_0_, region1_.name as name85_1_, region1_.state as state85_1_ from smartgrid.substation substation0_ right outer join smartgrid.region region1_ on substation0_.region_id=region1_.id
2014-05-15 15:50:31.123 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [1] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.123 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [1] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.123 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [8] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [1] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [null] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [4] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [2] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [7] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [7] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [7] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [9] as column [id91_0_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [7] as column [id85_1_]
2014-05-15 15:50:31.124 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] - found [null] as column [id91_0_]
------------------------------------Abbreviated Output------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why hibernate is returning null is because in the hibernate query:

```
from Substation sub right outer join fetch sub.region
```

we are returning a substation object, and when hibernate cannot find a substation (the case of region not having any substation), it does not have any object on which it could set the appropriate region values.

Also, not giving any thing before "from" makes the hibernate automatically modify the query and so it essentially becomes this:

```
select sub from Substation sub right outer join fetch sub.region
```

From this it can be seen clearly that we are specifically saying hibernate to return me the substation object. It does not matter if the region is eagerly loaded or not. When there is no substation to attach to, hibernate wont fetch the region region object.

I am not sure what I was expecting from hibernate - to automatically create a substation object and set all of its values to null except the region value. Pfff!! Take a look at this guy. Dumb.

Anyways, the correct query should be this:

```
select sub, reg from Substation sub inner join fetch Region reg sub.region = reg.id
```

This query will return two objects - Substation and Region. If substation is null, then the first object will be null, but you will still have the second object set which is what was required.

Comment: Upvote for the question as it interests me, downvote for the answer : it does not make any sense and in my opinion does not answer the original question : you've turned an outer join into inner join that is not equivalent.

Comment: @Andrei This is a very old thread so I don't remember exactly what I was up to, so I may be wrong here, but I think my problem was not around inner or outer join. It was more around what kind of answer is hibernate returning for last row result. I was thinking hibernate would return me a substation object with all fields marked as null except region. This is obviously wrong because that is not how hibernate works. So I changed my query to return substation and region both. `**Changing inner to outer is purely coincidental**`. I think this would work with `outer joins` as well.

Comment: Sorry, but the title of your question is "hql fetch on right outer join" (notice the "outer join" words in the title). Also, you're describing a situation that is most likely to appear during an outer join (I don't know if this is possible with an inner join).
Also, the query described in the answer section is, to my knowledge, invalid HQL (well, I could be wrong here, but it appears to be missing either a WHERE clause, or a WITH clause).

Comment: @Andrei Regarding title, you are correct, its misleading. Title should be "hibernate not returning expected results" or something similar. You are again right in saying that innerJoin is not replacement of outerJoin. For this reason I have removed my answer as "accepted". I will change the question and answer accordingly to reflect correct status. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Appreciate it :)